# Service Application stuck on stopping! How can i resolve this issue?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server, central-administration

Hi guys I accidentally installed two User Profiles Services, now i can't uninstall one, an d it's stuck on stopping state. Someone can help me? [image: Stuck on stopping]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, run this:

```
Get-SPServiceInstance
```

This will show a list of service Instances. Find your broken Service (Status will be Provisioning or Unprovisioning)

Get the GUID of this Service

Next

```
$srvc = Get-SPServiceInstance "GUID"
$srvc.Unprovision()
```

Comment: I've already done this! it's stop the user profile service, and the serviceApplication can´t be delete.

Comment: Solved! as the answer suggest.

Answer (score -1):

To get rid of a SharePoint Service Application and remove it completely using PowerShell. Here are the PowerShell cmdlets to Help you.

[image]

Viewing Service Applications in the Central Admin Console, it is stuck in a stopped state. The only way to force stop it is by running the following from an elevated PowerShell window:

```
stsadm -o provisionservice -action stop -servicetype "Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ProfileSynchronizationService, Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" -servicename FIMSynchronizationService
```

Another point to check is the security token on your server. You can do so by running the following command:

```
stsadm -o enumservices > c:\services.txt (Export results into a file and search, desired SharePoint service application will be disabled)
```

After this, delete the User Profile Service Application using below command:

```
Remove-SPServiceApplication "Desired Appliation GUIDE" -RemoveData
```

In order to get required SharePoint Service Application ID, try below command:

```
Get--SPServiceApplication
```

Copy GUIDE of the desired SharePoint Service Application