# Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Settings Service stuck on "Stopping"

Tags: sharepoint-server, spfx, 2016, sharepoint-on-prem, spservices

Stopping "Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Subscription Service" in SharePoint 2016 Server by using Power-shell command but it stuck at below line and not responding.

Remove-SPServiceApplication $SeviceApp -removedata -confirm:$false

When we check the status of Services in Central Admin > Manager Services its showing status "Stopping".

While status showing as "Stopping" we can see the Database is already created in DB server. In "Services in Farm" it is showing as processing instead of enable AutoProvision.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Service Application stuck on stopping! How can i resolve this issue?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134347/service-application-stuck-on-stopping-how-can-i-resolve-this-issue)

Comment: We tried those but it's not solved unfortunately... @Jammin4CO